# May the screen/keyboard be dedicated to a unique (background/non-root) process?

Tags: linux, terminal, tty, console, graphics

Consider an industrial computer (say "embedded system"),

- equipped with a linux server OS (no desktop)
- running just a SINGLE application process (a single non-root user)
- attached to an high resolution screen
- attached with a keyboard

The computer fully dedicated to a SINGLE application process/user,

- running in background (to be defined) and started at boot
- run some I/O logics
- get some user inputs (keystrokes/digits) from the keyboard
- has to display some text/images on a screen attached to the computer

> BTW, for text display details see also the related question: [display big texts (on a graphic mode?) without a desktop environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617603/display-big-texts-on-a-graphic-mode-without-a-desktop-environment/620845#620845)).

```
    linux server host (no desktop env)
    +-------------------------------------------+
    |                                           |
    |                                           +--------> Digital inputs
    |   +--------------+                        <--------- Digital outputs
    |   | graphic card |                        |
    +---+------+-------+--------------------^---+
               |                            |
               | HDMI / VGA                 | USB
+--------------v---------------+    +-------+--------+
| Please contact the operator. |    |                |
+------------------------------+    +----------------+
      screen (TTY console?)              keyboard
```

How can the (background) process print text (in text-terminal mode or in graphic mode) on the attached (dedicated) screen, and get keystrokes from the keyboard?

**OUTPUT**

For output, I presume that one solution is that the process prints output texts as images, directly writing on the framebuffer (by example using program `fbi`.

But how if I would use the screen as a `stdout` of the (background) process? In this case I  guess I need to "uncouple" the root TTY from the attached screen (that's possible?), allowing the user process to get the full control of the screen. It make sense?

**INPUT**

How can I take keystrokes from the keyboard? Using the stdin? Reading the keyboard device directly?

---

> BTW, I presume to access the computer for any (root) need, over SSH.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you'd want to replace `getty` with the program you want to run (or something that relays the input to your program)? https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Run_software_on_tty1_console_instead_of_login_getty.html

Comment: Or you use `cat /dev/tty1` (but this will block whatever is running in it frim getting the input). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440833/how-to-redirect-input-from-another-tty

Comment: Your question is confusing, it contains contradictions: Headless (meaning no display), and a description of a display. Please edit to remove any jargon words, and just say what you want.

Comment: Are you asking. How can I set up a system with a single graphical application, but no window-manager, start-button, task-bar, etc?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor headless === linux server (no desktop). Where is the contradiction? Anyway I removed the term headless if confuses.

Comment: "high resolution screen" the head. Maybe because it looks like a head and the computer part looks like shoulders (on a desktop configuration). Am I grokking you correctly?

Comment: Does this help? https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qt-embedded-running.html You can run a single app that's its own server process as well using embedded Qt ...

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking. How can I set up a system with a single graphical application, but no window-manager, start-button, task-bar, etc?

Then.

You just need to not run the desktop: Window manager, and panel. There are just other processes. The process that starts the X11 server, will also start these. You just need to change the configuration.

Comment: Yes, I'd avoid desktop, form some reasons. I don't want: windows manager multi users. No X11 server. No background related processes. What's your solution/proposal? Configuration of what?

Comment: Is the app just text? if it is graphical, then you need an X11 server (or wayland, or ..)